# Application fails to start - Parameter 0 of constructor in 'service' required a bean of type 'repository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, backend

Working on an application that uses Java / Spring Boot. We have two repos, an app and a "microservice." Running both works fine in a local environment. In staging, I get an

`org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://<microservice>:8080/api/v1/<placeholder>": Connection refused`

when the app is trying to make a call to the microservice.

Looking at microservice logs, I see the following:

```
Error creating bean with name 'service' defined in URL [jar:file:/workspace/<repository>/lib/<repository>-plain.jar!<service>.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'repository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

And

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in <service> required a bean of type <repository> that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type <repository> in your configuration.
```

The problem is, I cannot figure out 1) why the app starts up fine in a local environment but not staging, 2) what is causing the "required a bean of type" issue. I have other service/repo connections defined the same exact way that work fine. Code examples below:

Service that does not work:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class NotWorkingService {
    private NotWorkingRepository repository;
```

Repository that does not work:

```
public interface NotWorkingRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {

    public List<Entity> findAllByName(String name);
}
```

Here's a service that does work:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WorkingService {

    private WorkingRepository repository;
```

And its repository:

```
public interface WorkingRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {

    Optional<Entity> findBySerialNumber(String serialNumber);
```

They look exactly the same so I am baffled as to what is the problem.

I have looked at multiple existing questions but none of the answers seem to apply. I shouldn't need @Repository because I already have `extends JpaRepository`, I don't have anything @Autowired in either the working one or the not-working one, I have the @Service annotation, the directory structure is correct, I only see one application .jar file.

I'd appreciate any ideas here.

Here is the package structure (I can't share names of files, but the upper open directory is the working one and the lower one is the non-working one. The bottom file is the @SpringBootApplication:

[package structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbvLR.png)

The only difference I can see is the BaseInterface file? This is the contents:

```
public interface BaseInterface {
    // This class functions as a basePackageClass reference for AppJpaConfiguration
}
```

Maybe this is related to the problem? But, other working service/repository connections in the app don't have a BaseInterface.

Here is a collapsed version of the file structure:

[collapsed package structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlfRU.png)

Comment: What about package structure, could you share it ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa sure, just edited the post!

Comment: Yes the problem is that your main class couldn’t scan this repository. Can you declare new one in the same packages as working one ?

Comment: Also what about version of spring boot that you are using ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa hmm, but there are other packages at the same level that also have services and repositories and they work? I added a collapsed package structure picture to demonstrate. It looks like we are using spring boot version 3.1.6.

Comment: What about annotations from entities is imported from `javax` or `jakarta`? Be sure that it is from Jakarta, I mean annotations like `@Id` from persistence api

Comment: @AndreiLisa `@Entity` and `@Id` annotation for both working and non-working entities is coming from jakarta.persistence

Comment: Just do exactly as working one it should fix the problem

Comment: @AndreiLisa but they are the same. What should I do differently in the non-working one?

Comment: Post this code on github and I will be able to check and also to answer about it.

Comment: @ng17 in your application do you have any configuration file with `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation?

Comment: @kcsurapaneni yes I do! Do you think this might have something to do with it?

Comment: @ng17 yes, please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If a repository interface is located outside the specified `basePackages` or its sub-packages in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation, Spring Data JPA won't be able to discover and manage that repository. The `basePackages` attribute determines the root package(s) for scanning repository interfaces.

For instance, consider the following configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repository")
public class JpaConfig {
    // Additional configuration can be added here
}
```

In this setup, Spring Data JPA scans the "com.example.repository" package and its sub-packages for repository interfaces. If a repository interface is in a different package, say `com.example.other`, it won't be discovered:

```java
// This repository won't be discovered if outside "com.example.repository" and its sub-packages
package com.example.other;

public interface OtherRepository extends JpaRepository<OtherEntity, Long> {
    // ...
}
```

To ensure that all relevant repository interfaces are discovered, move the interface to a package within or under the specified `basePackages`.

Alternatively, you can use the `basePackageClasses` attribute of `@EnableJpaRepositories`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {RepositoryMarkerClass.class})
public class JpaConfig {
    // Additional configuration can be added here
}
```

Here, `RepositoryMarkerClass` is a marker class in the `com.example.repository` package, and Spring Data JPA uses its package for repository scanning:

```java
package com.example.repository;

public final class RepositoryMarkerClass {
    private RepositoryMarkerClass() {
        // Private constructor to prevent instantiation
    }
}
```

This ensures that all repository interfaces, even those outside the `basePackages`, are discovered and managed by Spring Data JPA.